# How do I use AutoFac with SignalR 2.0.0 where hubs are in an external dll?

Tags: signalr, autofac, signalr-hub

We have a need to be able to drop new projects/dlls into our main project and have the main project pick them up and be able to use them.  It was decided to use AutoFac to handle this need.  This way the main project would not need a direct reference to any of the other projects/dlls we want to use.  Here is the global.asax:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

var directoryName = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/bin/");
var cfg = new ModularityLoader(new ModularityConfig(Path.Combine(directoryName, @"Modules")), new Log4NetLogger(typeof(ModularityConfig)));
cfg.RegisterModulesFromCatalog(builder);

builder.RegisterType<AssembliesResolver>().AsImplementedInterfaces();
builder.RegisterType<AppsSecurityFeatureResolver>().AsImplementedInterfaces();
builder.RegisterType<FeaturesAutofacAuthoriztationFilter>()
    .AsWebApiAuthorizationFilterFor<ApiController>().InstancePerApiRequest();

builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

builder.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);

Container = builder.Build();
```

**We have post-build events on all projects that copy their dlls into the bin directory of our main project.  All of the dlls are loaded in here with *var cfg = new ModularityLoader*.**

See image:
[image: dll list screenshot]

builder.Build() calls the following class in any of the dlls in our project that implements Autofac.Module such as this one:

```
public class AutofacModuleConfig : Autofac.Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        base.Load(builder);
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(typeof(AutofacModuleConfig).Assembly);
    }
}
```

Here is where the trouble with SignalR comes in.  I would like to put RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs() into AutofacModuleConfig, but SignalR 2.0.0+ no longer supports this.  Instead, it wants you to create a Startup class like this:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup("SignalRConfig", typeof(KL.Apps.TestHarness.SignalR.Startup))]

namespace KL.Apps.TestHarness.SignalR
{
    public static class Startup
    {
        public static void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR("/signalr", new HubConfiguration());
        }
    }
}
```

Note:  To get this to work I added the following to the web.config:

```
<add key="owin:appStartup" value="SignalRConfig" />
```

SignalR also requires Hub classes like this:

```
[HubName("BatchHub")]
public class BatchHub : Hub
{
    public void RemoveBatchRow(Guid batchId)
    {
        Clients.All.RemoveBatchRow(batchId);
    }
}
```

Having the Startup class and Hub classes in my main project works perfectly.  However, because of the unique nature of AutoFac, none of my Hubs from my external dlls are getting loaded up.  I was thinking to try to find a way to force AutofacModuleConfig.Load to accept RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs(), but adding this line breaks the code.

I was thinking to go back to an earlier version of SignalR so I can use RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs() but I would really like to use the most up to date version.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

---

## EDIT 1:

I found this: https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/SignalRIntegration
It seems to be the answer the the problem.  However, RegisterHubs does not exist off of the builder object even after installing the Autofac.SignalR NuGet package...

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterHubs(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

---

## EDIT 2:

So this is what my AutofacModuleConfig looks like now, but my hubs are still not showing up in javascript.

```
namespace OurName.IOC
{
    public class AutofacModuleConfig : Autofac.Module
    {
        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            base.Load(builder);
            AutofacSignalRConfig.Load(builder);
            builder.RegisterApiControllers(typeof(AutofacModuleConfig).Assembly);
        }
    }
}

namespace Autofac.Integration.SignalR
{
    public static class AutofacSignalRConfig
    {
        public static void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.RegisterHubs(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        }
    }
}
```

Still not working though.  In javascript I cannot see my hubs.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var myHub = $.connection.BatchHub;
});
```

myHub is null.

---

## EDIT 3:

Tried this last night.  I removed AutofacSignalRConfig and this is how the main Global.asax looks now:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

var directoryName = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/bin/");
var cfg = new ModularityLoader(new ModularityConfig(Path.Combine(directoryName, @"Modules")), new Log4NetLogger(typeof(ModularityConfig)));
cfg.RegisterModulesFromCatalog(builder);

builder.RegisterType<AssembliesResolver>().AsImplementedInterfaces();
builder.RegisterType<AppsSecurityFeatureResolver>().AsImplementedInterfaces();
builder.RegisterType<FeaturesAutofacAuthoriztationFilter>()
    .AsWebApiAuthorizationFilterFor<ApiController>().InstancePerApiRequest();

builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

builder.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);

foreach (var assembly in cfg.LoadedAssemblies)
{
    var hubs = builder.RegisterHubs(assembly);
}

Container = builder.Build();

GlobalHost.DependencyResolver = new Autofac.Integration.SignalR.AutofacDependencyResolver(Container);
```

Notice how I tried to take the output of cfg (which is a collection of all assemblies found in the bin folder) and then foreach through them in order to execute builder.RegisterHubs on each one.  Still not picking up my hubs from any of those assemblies though.

Does there need to be a Startup class in each of my imported dlls too?  If so, how would I go about calling it?

---

## EDIT 4:

Tried this too with no success:

```
foreach (var assembly in cfg.LoadedAssemblies)
{
    //var hubs = builder.RegisterHubs(assembly);
    var a = assembly.GetExportedTypes().Where(x => x.BaseType == typeof (Hub));

    foreach (var x in a)
    {
        builder.RegisterType(x);
    }
}
```

See image for debug info:
[image: Another attempt at loading hubs]

---

## EDIT 5:

Jim Bolla thank you for the input.  Here is my first try at your suggestion.

```
public class AssemblyLocator : IAssemblyLocator
{
    public IList<Assembly> GetAssemblies()
    {
        var directoryName = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/bin/");
        var cfg = new ModularityLoader(new ModularityConfig(Path.Combine(directoryName, @"Modules")), new Log4NetLogger(typeof(ModularityConfig)));
        return cfg.LoadedAssemblies;
    }
}
```

Also added this just above Container = builder.Build:

`builder.RegisterType<AssemblyLocator>().As<IAssemblyLocator>().SingleInstance();`

AssemblyLocator.GetAssemblies() is now getting called.

... Testing ...

---

## EDIT 6:

Okay.  So now when I throw a breakpoint into javascript, I can see $.connection.BatchHub which is great!  However, when trying to call the hub method RemoveBatchRow on the server-side I get the following error:

"Using a Hub instance not created by the HubPipeline is unsupported."

Here is the stack trace:

> at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.NullClientProxy.TryInvokeMember(InvokeMemberBinder
>   binder, Object[] args, Object& result)    at CallSite.Target(Closure ,
>   CallSite , Object , Guid )    at
>   System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid2[T0,T1](CallSite
>   site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)    at
>   KL.Apps.WebIndex.Hubs.BatchHub.RemoveBatchRow(Guid batchId) in
>   d:\Source\Apps Framework
>   Modules\WebIndex\Main\Source\KL.Apps.WebIndex\Hubs\BatchHub.cs:line 20
>   at
>   KL.Apps.WebIndex.API.Batch.BatchLockController.TryLockBatchAsync(String
>   batchId) in d:\Source\Apps Framework
>   Modules\WebIndex\Main\Source\KL.Apps.WebIndex\API\Batch\BatchLockController.cs:line
>   30    at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )    at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass13.b__c(Object
>   instance, Object[] methodParameters)    at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object
>   instance, Object[] arguments)    at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.<>c__DisplayClass5.b__4()
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.RunSynchronously[TResult](Func`1
>   func, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

I am calling the hub method from one of my remote dlls like this:

```
new BatchHub().RemoveBatchRow(gId);
```

You can see the definition for BatchHub above.

Any other ideas?

Comment: RegisterHubs is an extension method defined in the class Autofac.Integration.SignalR.RegistrationExtensions in the assembly Autofac.Integration.SignalR.dll. Make sure your using that namespace.

Comment: Ok.  Did that and now I have the method.  However, in my front end it still is not picking up my Hubs.

Edited my original post to reflect latest changes.

Comment: Are the hubs in the same assembly as your AutofacSignalRConfig class? If you set a breakpoint in its Load method, does it get hit when your app starts up?

Comment: Yes they are in the same assembly as AutofacSignalRConfig.  Also yes, it does get hit when the app starts up.

Comment: Made some modifications to try something else and noted them in "Edit 3".  Still no success.

Comment: I don't see any reason why your hubs wouldn't be registered with Autofac at this point. It seems to me that it's something with SignalR and how it resolves hubs. I'm guessing it has something to do with the DefaultHubManager class. If you look at https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Hubs/Lookup/DefaultHubManager.cs you'll see mentions of IHubDescriptorProvider which is how SignalR goes from a hub name to a HubDescriptor. I'm guessing this is returning null for your hubs.

Comment: I pulled the code for SignalR. `DefaultHubManager` is probably using `ReflectedHubDescriptorProvider` which is probably using `DefaultAssemblyLocator` which does `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` to tell SignalR where to find hubs. The good news is if you implemement `IAssemblyLocator` and register it with autofac, I think your code will work.

Comment: Jim, thanks for your reply.  I put my latest in "Edit 5".  Doesn't seem to be working out...

Comment: Jim.  The IAssemblyLocator idea might actually be working.  I forgot to comment one thing back in from when I was testing.
Doing some testing now to see if it really works.  Will come back when done. :)

Comment: Ok, still stuck but it looks like we are making progress.  Updated with "Edit 6".  I can now see my methods in javascript $.connection.BatchHub (which was not the case before), but when I try to call them on the server side I get the exception "Using a Hub instance not created by the HubPipeline is unsupported."

Comment: You can't instantiate Hubs outside the SignalR pipeline. That's just the way it works.

Comment: Reworking things to instantiate from javascript.

Comment: Jim.  I can officially say that this is working perfectly.  Thanks!